# How can I IMPORTXML YouTube video count to Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, youtube, importxml

I'm doing a Google Sheets training video on using XPATH and IMPORTXML on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pwZ44kAeiOo&index=5&list=PLv9Pf9aNgemsiiIRzdpK-6Bm6-EpmyS9X) but YouTube seems to have updated their site and now the import option won't work for extracting total video views.

Does anyone how to do this?

The closest I got is:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8p19gUXJYTsUPEpusHgteQ/videos","//div[@class='style-scope.ytd-grid-video-renderer']/span/text")'
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe:

```
=+importxml("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8p19gUXJYTsUPEpusHgteQ","//*[contains (@class, 'view-count')]")
```

If you want the number only (say for further processing):

```
=--REGEXEXTRACT(+importxml("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC8p19gUXJYTsUPEpusHgteQ","//*[@class='view-count']"),"[\d|,]+")
```